# scope 'Mail.ReadBasic.All' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm connecting to Microsoft Graph Api in order to download all user emails. I get it working to download all emails for the user that makes the authentication, - it works for scope **Mail.ReadBasic**. However when I try to authenticate as "global admin" with scope **Mail.ReadBasic.All** I get the following error:

`AADSTS650053: The application 'xxx' asked for scope 'Mail.ReadBasic.All' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor.`

The app has allowed the scope Mail.ReadBasic.All in the settings of Azure portal.

```py
def authenticate():
    parameters = {
        "client_id": settings["app_id"],
        "response_mode": "form_post",
        "scope": "Mail.ReadBasic.All User.ReadBasic.All offline_access",
        "response_type": "code",
        "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8000/",
        "tenant": settings["tenant"]
    }

    url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)
    return url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail.ReadBasic.All is only available as a application permission scope not a delegated permission scope. You can consent this in the portal.azure.com application registration screen for the application and use admin consent there for it to work.

This is currently only supported on /beta endpoint, not /v1.0 endpoint too as its a preview permission scope.

Comment: I figured that finally, too :D Do you know any difference between Mail.ReadBasic and Mail.ReadBasic.All, (both for application permission). From the information in azure portal, it seems as if they were the same.

Comment: There is no difference, other than .All will give you access to all mailboxes when admin consented.

Comment: Well, that's the thing... With admin consent, Mail.ReadBasic, I still get access to all mailboxes in the tenant.

Comment: We are actually transitioning. When we introduced Mail.Read with the first wave of Graph. Then we realized it made more sense to introduce the *.All.  We cannot change the behavoiur of Mail.Read as itd be a breaking change. So instead when we introduced a finer grained scope of Mail.ReadBasic, we decided to have Mail.ReadBasic and Mail.ReadBasic.All. The former being consistent with Mail.Read. The later being consistent with User.ReadBasic.All and so on.

Comment: Aah, I see. Thank you very much for your time!